# How to calculate large-scale inverse matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

As we know that we can calculate the inverse matrix with the help of numpy as the following.

```
matrix1 = np.matrix([[8,2,5],[7,3,1],[4,9,6]])
inverse_matrix1 = matrix1.I
result = np.matmul(matrix1, inverse_matrix1)
```

The result is as the following and it is easy for us to check the accuracy simply by doing np.matmul.

```
matrix([[ 0.03585657,  0.1314741 , -0.05179283],
    [-0.15139442,  0.11155378,  0.10756972],
    [ 0.20318725, -0.25498008,  0.03984064]])
```

The checked result is as the following.

```
matrix([[ 1.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  2.77555756e-17],
    [ 0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00,  3.46944695e-17],
    [-2.22044605e-16,  0.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00]])
```

However, this case is very small. In practice, although we should avoid calculating the inverse matrix for the large matrix, sometimes we have to do that. I found that matrix.I cannot provide me a relatively accurate inverse matrix when the matrix is relatively large. The example is shown as the following. I want to calculate the inverse matrix of a Gaussian Kernel Matrix whose shape is (300, 300).

```
point = np.reshape(np.linspace(-5.0, 5.0, 300), (300, 1))
kernel_matrix_np = np.exp(-(point - np.transpose(point))**2 / (2 * 2**2))
```

I am not sure how I can calculate such matrix. Thank you so much!

Comment: `numpy.matrix` and its methods should be considered deprecated, use arrays instead.  Try [`scipy.linalg.inv`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.html); I don't expect it to be dramatically better but SciPy is more likely to be fine tuned. The double precision of floats limits what one can do with large ill posed problems.

Comment: I think your condition number is too large [`np.linalg.cond(kernel_matrix_np)`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261295/to-invert-a-matrix-condition-number-should-be-less-than-what). You can calculate such matrix, but because of roundoff errors, you shouldn't

Comment: Thank you for both of your contributions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in results between your examples isn't due to the size of the matrices, it's due to the rank.  The first matrix is full rank

```
>>> matrix_rank(matrix1)
3  ## Shape of the matrix
```

the shape of the matrix), while in the second case the matrix is of rank 19.

```
>>> matrix_rank(kernel_matrix_np)
19   ## Much less than the shape of the matrix
```

It isn't possible to recover the original matrix in this case - a full rank matrix is required.  As @Brenlla mentioned, this is reflected in the condition number.  Roughly speaking each order of magnitude in the condition number represents one digit of precision lost.

```
>>> cond(kernel_matrix_np)
1.9605027391309521e+19
```

These are just two things to check any time calculations are made using matrices, and generally one of these will indicate where a problem is.  Lastly, there are some cases using `pinv` in place of `inv` gives slightly better results, although that won't work in this case since the matrix isn't full rank.

Comment: Thank you so much! Due to my careless, I did not notice if my matrix possesses the inverse matrix.